# Problems with static maps and images

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to add a map image to a panel in Google Apps Script.  Every time I load the UI, I am greeted with the following image:

[image]

This is the Google image for being over your quota.  Well, I've never used the maps functionality before.  I get the same result on two different domains/different accounts.  There's no reason I should be over any limit.

Here's a simple script that's broke:

```
function main() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();

  var map = Maps.newStaticMap()
      .setCenter("1600 Pennsylvania Ave, Washington D.C.")
      .setZoom(14);

  var mapUrl = map.getMapUrl();

  var image = app.createImage(mapUrl);
  panel.add(image);

  // add a label with the URL string
  var labelUrl = app.createLabel(mapUrl);
  app.add(labelUrl);  

  app.add(panel);

  sheet.show(app);
}
```

And actually, while writing this example, I saw that it would work sometimes, and not others.  I'm really confused.

In the example above, the URL is also written to a label on the UI.  If I manually copy that and paste into my web browser, I have no issues viewing the map.

Anyone else experiencing this?  Have some tips?

Comment: Are you using a library? Where is `Maps` defined?

Comment: @EduardoCereto [Maps is a default service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_maps?hl=fr-FR) in google apps script

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest that you raise an issue on the Issue Tracker if you are 100% sure that you haven't hit the quota limits. (recollect if you have any other scripts left of triggers that can eat into your quota)

Comment: Thanks - I'm new to this, so didn't know where to turn.  I just entered a ticket:  [link](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1391)

Answer (score 0):

One possibility that I haven't seen anywhere else is that you might have your **API Key locked down by IP**. Frustratingly, Google gives you this same image whether you are over quota, or the IP is blocked.

In the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/), check under API & Auth -> Credentials and click "Edit Allowed IP's". Be careful opening that up, as anyone can take your API Key and stick you with the usage.